# Interactive Ruby script

Tags: ruby, telnet, interactive

I'm trying to write a ruby script that logs into a remote server, switches to another user, executes a script and answers questions to that script. Right now, I can log in but it hangs on the execution of the bash script. I'm not sure if I got the prompt part right but it's not getting to that point yet. It "hangs" on the running of the script or it just isn't printing the output of the script to the screen.

Here's what I got for now:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/telnet'

s = Net::SSH::Telnet.new("Host" => "server1", "Username" => "dev", "Password" => "12345", "Prompt" => /[$%#>] \z/n)

puts s.cmd("sudo -s")
puts s.cmd("su - user1")
puts s.cmd("/opt/develop/develop-bin/start.sh")
puts s.waitfor(/Prompt/)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try replacing `s.waitFor(/Prompt/)` with `s.waitFor(/.*/)` and see what is actually returned

Comment: sawa- I guess what I'm getting at is that I can't see the output of the bash script that I'm trying to execute. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way.

Comment: Uri - Thanks! But...I'm not even to that point yet, it "hangs" on the execution of the bash script. I think the output is just not showing up on the screen and it's just waiting for me to answer the question that the script is asking but it's hidden in the background. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet that works for me. It is taken from the bigger library, so treat it as an example. Fill up the variables `command`, `username`, `password`, `servername` and `sudoer` and give a try

```
class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end

AUTH_METHODS = ['hostbased', 'password', 'keyboard-interactive']
MYPROMPT = SecureRandom.hex # or whatever you want

ret = ""
stderr_data = ""

Net::SSH.start(servername, username, :password => password, :auth_methods => AUTH_METHODS) do |ssh|
  ssh.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.on_data do |channel, data|
      ret += data 
      raise AuthenticationError, "SUDO ACCESS DENIED" if data.inspect.include?('Sorry, try again.') || data.inspect.include?('not in sudoers')
      channel.send_data(password+"\n") if data.inspect.include? MYPROMPT
      sleep 0.1
    end
    channel.on_extended_data do |ch, type, data|
      stderr_data+=data
    end
    channel.request_pty
    channel.exec("sudo -p #{MYPROMPT} su - #{sudoer} -c '#{command}'")
    channel.wait
  end
end

puts ret.gsub(/^"/,'').gsub(/"$/,'')
```